# how to force bower to install a certain version of dependency

Tags: bower

Assume a `bower.json` file in which dependencies are like

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.5.x",
    "angular-routing": "*",
    "ngDialog": "*",
    "requirejs": "*"
}
```

because  `angular-routing` requires another version of `angular` (say `1.2.x`), bower prompts me to choose a version.

How could I force bower to install `angular ~1.5.x` automatically?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I figured out the answer. I'm sharing for others:

If I add the dependency with my favorite version to `resolutions` in `bower.json`, Bower will automatically install it. Here is my updated `bower.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "angular": "~1.5.x",
  "angular-routing": "*",
  "ngDialog": "*",
  "requirejs": "*"
},
"resolutions": {
  "angular": "~1.5.x"
}
```

More information [here](https://jaketrent.com/post/bower-resolutions/).

**Update:**
As Mattliu mentioned in comments, it's possible to answer with `!` when any library asks for another version of an already installed dependency. this way you'll keep existing version and also `npm` creates `resolution` config automatically.

Comment: If you've found a better solution, please let me know

Comment: When you are asked to choose a version, you can also prefix the selection with a `!` and it will automatically update your `bower.json` with a `"resolutions"` json.

Comment: @mattliu Thank you. I'll update my answer to include this

Answer (score 38):

If you would like to install JQuery 2.1.4 strictly and add it to your bower.json dependencies you would go like this

```
bower install jQuery#2.1.4 --save
```

Comment: This does not require modifying bower.json by hand. This should be accept answer.

Answer (score 5):

- You need to specify the version in bower.json.
- Note that using a tilde *will automatically resolve to any newer minor version*
- So, specifying ~1.5.x would pull 1.5.1 if it existed
- To specify an *exact* version, remove the tilde e.g. specify "1.5.1"

Comment: Thank you. you're right. Here my problem was between angular `1.2.x` and `1.5.x` which makes a breaking difference. that's why I like to have any patch releases in `1.5.x` but not other minor releases.